# I am using EMOX and Mosquitto MQTT brokers .Which are the suitable clients for both?Does PAHO client support both?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho, emqx

I am using EMOX and Mosquitto MQTT brokers .Which are the suitable clients for both?Does PAHO client support both?

Or please help e understand which are the suitable clients to publish messages to these brokers

Answer (score 1):

All MQTT clients should support all MQTT brokers (with the obvious exception that you will need a MQTTv5 client to support MQTTv5 features on a broker)